# Creating a dictionary in pandas by mapping column values to headers

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following data frame:

```
F1:


head       drowsiness     sweat       
head_P     D_P            sw_f
head_S     D-H            sw_h
head_F     D_L            sw_l
```

I need to create a dictionary by mapping all the values in columns to the header of the columns as follows:

```
Dic = {head_p:head, head_S: head, head_F: head,  D_P: drowsiness, D-H:drowsiness ,  D_L: drowsiness,   sw_f: sweat,  sw_h: sweat , sw_l: sweat }
```

I created a list of each column and mapped it to the header, but I do not know how to create such a dictionary. Thank you!

Comment: You should understand that dictionaries cannot contain duplicate keys, so this is not possible. What else do you have in mind?

Comment: @COLDSPEED, I am sorry, I edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`melt` + `set_index` + `to_dict`:

```
df

     head drowsiness sweat
0  head_P        D_P  sw_f
1  head_S        D-H  sw_h
2  head_F        D_L  sw_l

df.melt().set_index('value').to_dict()['variable']

{'D-H': 'drowsiness',
 'D_L': 'drowsiness',
 'D_P': 'drowsiness',
 'head_F': 'head',
 'head_P': 'head',
 'head_S': 'head',
 'sw_f': 'sweat',
 'sw_h': 'sweat',
 'sw_l': 'sweat'}
```

---

If you get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'melt
```

That means you're using an older version of pandas (<0.20), so instead, use `pd.melt`:

```
pd.melt(df).set_index('value').to_dict()['variable']
```

Comment: it returns the following error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'melt'

Comment: @Mary You must be using an old version of pandas. Change to `pd.melt(df).set_index('value').to_dict()['variable']`

Answer (score 3):

Add `T`

```
df.melt().set_index('value').T.to_dict('records')
Out[277]: 
[{'D-H': 'drowsiness',
  'D_L': 'drowsiness',
  'D_P': 'drowsiness',
  'head_F': 'head',
  'head_P': 'head',
  'head_S': 'head',
  'sw_f': 'sweat',
  'sw_h': 'sweat',
  'sw_l': 'sweat'}]
```

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**

```
dict(zip(df.values.ravel(), df.columns.repeat(len(df))))

{'D-H': 'drowsiness',
 'D_L': 'sweat',
 'D_P': 'head',
 'head_F': 'sweat',
 'head_P': 'head',
 'head_S': 'drowsiness',
 'sw_f': 'head',
 'sw_h': 'drowsiness',
 'sw_l': 'sweat'}
```

---

**Option 2**

```
dict((v, h) for r, h in zip(df.values, df.columns) for v in r)

{'D-H': 'drowsiness',
 'D_L': 'sweat',
 'D_P': 'head',
 'head_F': 'sweat',
 'head_P': 'head',
 'head_S': 'drowsiness',
 'sw_f': 'head',
 'sw_h': 'drowsiness',
 'sw_l': 'sweat'}
```

Comment: dude nice one :)